# How to authenticate with Service Principal and get the latest 2-3 Azure repository tags in .NET/Core?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am writing an API that accesses the Azure Container Registry (ACR), authenticating w/ a Service Principal. The end-goal is to be able to fetch the latest tags of all containers currently in the repository.

If possible, I want to avoid using PowerShell since that's just additional overhead and calling the Azure API's in the end. Ideally, there's already a library for this in Azure SDK. If not, any pointers on doing this through the (Azure AD?) API would help greatly.

I'm currently looking at this library (https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master) and trying to get a sample application working to see if I can log in. And move on from there.

This is what I'd like to achieve, and I can manually do this through the Azure CLI:

```
az login --service-principal -u $username -p $password --tenant $tenant

az acr repository show-tags `
--subscription $subscriptionId -n $registryName `
--repository $repositoryName `
--detail --orderby time_desc --top 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use Azure C# SDK for this, because this is a container registry level API, not Azure level API. You need to use some sort of library that would allow to talk to the Docker Registry API ([like the random one I've found](https://github.com/CaptiveAire/Docker.Registry.DotNet)).

Azure [doesn't expose that api through ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/).